# How to Plot this equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have the following equation.

```
R^2 = 1 - 2 Sqrt[\[Omega] (G - \[Omega])]
```

I want to plot `R` with the variation of `τ`.

The relation between `ω` and `τ` can be defined as follows

```
ω = -(G/2) (Cos[τ + ω ϵ τ] - 1)
```

and

```
τ = 1/(1 + ω ϵ) (ArcCos[1 - (2 ω)/G])
```

How to plot `R` with `τ`.

I have used the following command

```
ω =-(G/2) (Cos[τ + ω ϵ τ] - 1)
ContourPlot[R^2 == 1 - 2 Sqrt[ω (G - ω)], {τ, 0, 30}, {R, 0, 2}]
```

but it does not give any result.

Here `G=0.8`,  `ϵ` is `0.1`, `τ` can be varied from 0 to 30.

Comment: The first line is not an equation. Therefore there is nothing I can solve for $R$.

Comment: Also, the second equation needs to be solved for `ω`, while the equation is non-trivial. Are you sure, that this is what you need?

Comment: I think you should take a look at basic tutorials as you are confusing `==` and `=`. You could start from [Fast Introduction for Programmers: Assignments](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/assignments/).

Comment: Now, the definition of $\omega$ does not make sense, as it is a function of itself. It is a *recursive* definition and *Mathematica* will just give an error and will not `Set` the value for $\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

Your equations are only consistent for discrete values of `{τ, ω, R}`

```
eqns = R^2 - 1 + G Cos[τ + ω ε τ] == 0 &&
   ω == -(G/2) (Cos[τ + ω ε] τ] - 1) &&
   τ == 1/(1 + ω ε) (ArcCos[1 - (2 ω)/G]);

pts = {τ, ω, R} /. {Reduce[eqns /. {G -> 4/5, ε -> 1/10} // 
      Simplify, {R, τ, ω}, Reals] // ToRules}

(* {{(25 π)/27, 4/5, -(3/Sqrt[5])}, {0, 0, -(1/Sqrt[5])}, {0, 0, 1/Sqrt[5]}, 
  {(25 π)/27, 4/5, 3/Sqrt[5]}} *)

pts // N

(* {{2.90888, 0.8, -1.34164}, {0., 0., -0.447214}, {0., 0., 0.447214}, 
  {2.90888, 0.8, 1.34164}} *)

Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
  Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@ pts},
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"τ", "ω", "R"}),
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
G = 8/10; ϵ = 1/10;
r = Sqrt[1 - 2 Sqrt[ω (G - ω)]];
t = 1/(1 + ω ϵ) (ArcCos[1 - (2 ω)/G]);
ParametricPlot[{t, r}, {ω, -2, 2}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"τ", "R"}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Really good guess! :)